# Preventing asserts from failing tests in Codeception

Tags: codeception

I've just started exploring automated testing, specifically Codeception, as part of my QA work at a web design studio. The biggest issue I'm experiencing is having Codeception fail a test as soon as an assert fails, no matter where it's placed in the code. If my internet connection hiccups or is too slow, things can become difficult. I was wondering if there were methods to provide more control over when Codeception will fail and terminate a test session, or even better, a way to retry or execute a different block or loop of commands when an assert does fail. For example, I would like to do something similar to the following:

```
if ( $I->see('Foo') )
{
     echo 'Pass';
}
else
{
     echo 'Fail';
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions that could help accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understand it correctly, but I think, you should try to use Cest.

```
$ php codecept.phar generate:cest suitename CestName
```

So you could write one test in one test function. If a test fails, it will abort. You can also configure codeception, that it will not abort and show only the one test which fails in a summary at the end of all tests.

See here in the documentation: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.0/docs/07-AdvancedUsage.md

Maybe it's better to use:

```
$I::dontSee('Foo');
```

Regards

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was hard to follow, but this was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a conditional assertion:

```
   $I->canSeeInCurrentUrl('/user/miles');
   $I->canSeeCheckboxIsChecked('#agree');
   $I->cantSeeInField('user[name]', 'Miles');
```

The [codeception documentation](http://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests#Conditional-Assertions) says:

> Sometimes you don't want the test to be stopped when an assertion fails. Maybe you have a long-running test and you want it to run to the end. In this case you can use conditional assertions. Each see method has a corresponding canSee method, and dontSee has a cantSee method.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work at present when running Codeception in PhpStorm. . I have two dontSee() assertions that fail. If I change them to cantsee(), the test continues, but there's no indication that those assertions failed. It works fine from the command line.